# svg image is not loading in xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, svg, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

i am trying to load svg image but nothing shows up.

I set image to `embedded resources` and path of image is:

[image]

[ref plugin](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/SVG-support)

```
xmlns:ffsvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"

<ffsvg:SvgCachedImage Source="resources://IDCardWallet.Resources.infographic.phone.svg"  />
```

Comment: i also tried adding height / width with no luck

Comment: "resource://", not "resources://"

Comment: did not noticed it thanks. that worked